# Заменить ключи при конвертации csv в json

Tags: php, json, csv

у меня есть файл csv с товарами и его нужно конвертировать в json файл, только при конвертации заменить ключи на те что нужны для импорта 1c.

```
 <?php
function utf8_converter($array)
{
    array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$item, $key){
        if(!mb_detect_encoding($item, 'utf-8', true)){
            $item = utf8_encode($item);
        }
    });

    return $array;
}

// php function to convert csv to json format
function csvToJson($fname) {
    // open csv file
    if (!($fp = fopen($fname, 'r'))) {
        die("Can't open file...");
    }

    //read csv headers
    $key = fgetcsv($fp,"1024",",");

    // parse csv rows into array
    $json = array();
    while ($row = fgetcsv($fp,"1024",",")) {
        $json[] = array_combine($key, $row);
    }

    // release file handle
    fclose($fp);

    // encode array to json
    return json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
if (file_put_contents("data.json", csvToJson("main.csv")))
    echo "JSON file created successfully...";
else
    echo "Oops! Error creating json file...";
// print_r();
?>
```

Вот такой код у меня есть который я нашел для конвертации в json
но мне нужно при конвертации пройтись массивами и заменить с:

```
"КОД":"1-00300265",
      "НАЗВАНИЕ":"Какое то название товара",
      "kategoria_1":"Категория",
      "kategoria_2":"Категория2",
      "kategoria_3":"Игрушки",
      "kategoria_4":"",
      "marka":"",
      "zakup eur":"3,25",
      "exportv eur":"5,59",
      "штрих код":"8053629693858",
      "опис":"Это пример описание для товара"
```

на:
"product_erp_id": "024fba39-ecc8-11e8-808c-c412f5310745",
"products_erp_code": "6603BI0523",
"name": "Какое то название товара",
"is_archival": 1,
"ean": "6959532330922",
"Delete": 0,
"description": "Это пример описание для товара"

Помогите если знаете как мне это сделать, только я новичок-новичок в пхп и вряд ли пойму если вы будете мне логику только рассказывать. Если кому не сложно, помогите кодом. Заранее спасибо большое

Comment: не вижу вззаимосвязи между первым и вторым массивом

Answer (score 0):

Простите, забыл оформить то, на что мне нужно заменить

```
"product_erp_id": "024fba39-ecc8-11e8-808c-c412f5310745",
  "products_erp_code": "6603BI0523",
  "name": "Какое то название",
  "is_archival": 1,
  "ean": "6959532330922",
  "Delete": 0,
  "description": "Какое то описание"
```